# Adjust packagexml

Tags: ros, package.xml, packages, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF and when I "catkin_create_pkg robot_setup_tf roscpp tf geometry_msgs" I have this message: "Please adjust the values in package.xml.". This file is:

```
<package>
<name>robot_setup_tf</name>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<description>The robot_setup_tf package</description>
<!-- One maintainer tag required, multiple allowed, one person per tag 
-->
<!-- Example:  -->
<!-- <maintainer email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</maintainer> 
-->
<maintainer email="antonio@todo.todo">antonio</maintainer>
<!-- One license tag required, multiple allowed, one license per tag 
-->
<!-- Commonly used license strings: -->
<!--   BSD, MIT, Boost Software License, GPLv2, GPLv3, LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3 
-->
<license>TODO</license>
<!-- Url tags are optional, but mutiple are allowed, one per tag 
-->
<!-- Optional attribute type can be: website, bugtracker, or repository 
-->
<!-- Example: -->
<!-- <url type="website">http://wiki.ros.org/robot_setup_tf</url> 
--><!-- Author tags are optional, mutiple are allowed, one per tag 
--><!-- Authors do not have to be maintianers, but could be 
--><!-- Example: -->
<!-- <author email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</author> 
--><!-- The *_depend tags are used to specify dependencies 
--><!-- Dependencies can be catkin packages or system dependencies 
--><!-- Examples: -->
<!-- Use build_depend for packages you need at compile time: 
--><!--   <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend> 
--><!-- Use buildtool_depend for build tool packages: -->
<!--   <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend> -->
<!-- Use run_depend for packages you need at runtime: -->
<!--   <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend> -->
<!-- Use test_depend for packages you need only for testing: 
--><!--   <test_depend>gtest</test_depend> -->
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<build_depend>tf</build_depend>
<run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
<run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
<run_depend>tf</run_depend>
<!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
<export>
<!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here 
--></export>
</package>
```

What I have to change? Can I leave it? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228662/adjust-packagexml/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Once you've created a package.xml, you should set the license (`<license>` tags) and the maintainer name (`<maintainer>` tags).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1